# Gradle 2.0.0-beta4 makes AndroidAnnotation doesn't work

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations, android-apt

With `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'` and `'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'`, AndroidAnnotation works well with processing the annotation. But after I update to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta4'` for instant run, it seems AndroidAnnotation cannot generate @EApplication. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use AA 4.0-SNAPSHOT for this.

Add repository for AA snapshots:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}
```

Change AA version to 4.0-SNAPSHOT

```
dependencies {
   compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.0-SNAPSHOT"
   apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Add `library:true` to `apt` argument:

```
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId

        //only for Android Annotations 4.0-SNAPSHOT 
        library 'true'
    }
}
```

This way AA does not validate the presence of `EApplication`, `EActivity` etc. in your manifest, hence it will compile with Instant Run. The cause is that Instant Run changes your application class in the manifest, that is why AA cannot find the generated one in it.

**Update:** AA 4.0-SNAPSHOT is modularized, that means you have to add the AA REST client module as well in your build.gradle

```
org.androidannotations:rest-spring:4.0-SNAPSHOT
org.androidannotations:rest-spring-api:4.0-SNAPSHOT
```

And you have to change the REST annotation imports to `org.androidannotations.rest.spring.annotations.*`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. As your answer, here is the error I get:
`Error:(3, 47) error: package org.androidannotations.annotations.rest does not exist
Error:(4, 47) error: package org.androidannotations.annotations.rest does not exist
Error:(5, 39) error: package org.androidannotations.api.rest does not exist
Error:(13, 33) error: cannot find symbol class RestClientErrorHandling
Error:(12, 2) error: cannot find symbol class Rest
Error:(34, 6) error: cannot find symbol class Get`